# When do browsers add CSS styles as attributes, even though these have not been specified explicitly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Dear *StackOverflowers*,

I am currently working on a web-site and I happened to stumble across a *weird* CSS style interpretation.

What I get is

```
<div id="..." style="padding-bottom: 78px; padding-top: 78px;" >...</div>
```

for elements that **do not have** these styles specified anywhere, and even if I view the page source, there is no such styles!

So, the question is, **what could be the reason for these styles appearing *out of nowhere***?

In my particular case there are following styles assigned to the `<div>` element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 100%;
-moz-box-align: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
display: -moz-box;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-top: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Using any browser (Firefox/Chrome/Internet Explorer) I can see that `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` styles get overridden with those *inline* styles mentioned above.

What am I missing here? Where should I search for hints?

Comment: simple solution add here outline:red 5px solid; u ll see where it is applying

Comment: They are inline styles. They are either in the HTML or have been applied by JS.

Comment: most likely a JS library that you're using... Comment out all links to JS libraries/code and gradually re-introduce them to get the offending script...

Comment: Also double check for an external style sheet. The reference is usually in the head section in a <link> tag.

Comment: @M.chaudhry: Sorry, I did not get your suggestions. Where do I put that outline? The browser says the styles are specific to the element. However, these aren't defined in any CSS files (nor JS files)

Comment: Paulie_D: No, these are not present in the HTML. However, these are present in the DOM explorer in any browser.

Comment: @shennan: I have though of that as well, however, commenting all JS scripts does not change these styles. Currently I am getting more concerned about particular styles behaviour, like, `box-sizing`... Maybe these styles are interpreted weirdly by browsers?

Comment: can we see a page? either a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or (better) the actual page you're working on?

Comment: @shennan: I will try to reproduce the issue in a small example and put it on [fiddle](http://fiddle.net) and then update my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as suggested in the comments, the reason for such (*weird*) behavior was really actually JavaScript.

At first I thought it was not, because I was sure to have all the JS scripts removed from my page, however, there were a couple left.

Thank you everybody, especially [shennan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726766/shennan) and [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) for the ideas.